# Overwrite manifest (themes)

Tags: android-activity, permissions, appcelerator, manifest, appcelerator-titanium

I have a project that has 3 themes (support,crm,sales), when I compile a version, I have to change the tiapp.xml:

- id (com.website.[support/crm/sales])
- name (Website [Support/CRM/Sales])
- android manifest

My question is: there are any way to replace or merge the android manifest or some parts of tiapp.xml file:

- uses-permission android:name="com.website[**support/crm/sales**].permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
- permission android:name="com.website.[**support/crm/sales**].permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
- activity android:name=".Website[**Support/CRM/Sales**]Activity"

This is my manifest:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23"
            android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.website.[support/crm/sales].permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <permission
            android:name="com.website.[support/crm/sales].permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <application android:debuggable="true"
            android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDcN-CWFqg4-Ai4Es10E0sSDmJ7seo4XAg"/>
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".Website[Support/CRM/Sales]Activity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        </application>
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

The main/default icons, I've to replace them manually, while this feature isn't added: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1318

Comment: I've found this: https://github.com/jasonkneen/tith, but there is no default way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `tiapp.xml` is amongst the few things you cannot theme through Alloy yet:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1118

This because a chicken-egg problem. `tiapp.xml` is the main config file of your app which is loaded before anything else.

I'd suggest using `grunt` or `gulp` to modify the file before you hand it over to Titanium to build.